# How to get a value from JTable 1 to JTable 2?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have no idea how to pass a value from `jtable1` to `jtable2`. For an example, When I double-click the row from `jtable1`, and it will display the same value at `jtable2`. Any idea? I think hard for a long time, and I can't solve the problem.

Comment: Can you make your question clear so we can help you, please?

Comment: [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdPNi_xkBnA)
it something like this but what i need is getting the value from jtable to another jtable. Not jtable to jtextfield :((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to transfer value from one `jTable` to another `jTable` within the same JFrame, in the mouse click event of `jTable1` give

```
    jTable2.setValueAt(jTable1.getValueAt(0, 0).toString(), 0, 0);

    jTable2.setValueAt(jTable1.getValueAt(0, 1).toString(), 0, 1);

    jTable2.setValueAt(jTable1.getValueAt(0, 2).toString(), 0, 2);
```

Hope this will resolve your problem...

Answer (score 1):

Study the tutorial section [*How to Use Tables: User Selections*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection) and learn how to [*How to Write a List Selection Listener*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html). In your `jtable1` listener, you can update the `TableModel` of `jtable2` to display any related data.

Comment: The linked video _appears_ to be about linking a `Table`Model` to MySQL in the NetBeans GUI editor. OP might want a shared model, separate models, or separate models sharing a common data source.

Comment: aaach I see this is about BeansBindings, I'd suggest to use BeansBindings only to my arch-enemy (Jeanette or Rob can to use that correctly), because I saw there performance issue, around us are `ResultsetTableModels` with flag `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE`, but I never tried those